Executing multiple mvn commands in parallel causes mvn to get stuck
I have a pipeline that runs a mvn project in the following way:
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="MyMavenProject"
This project is located in work-repo and works with input and output files, whose names are always the same: input.json and output.json.
The pipeline is listening to data-repo and every time someone pushes a json file to data-repo, the pipeline creates a run dir with that file's name, clones work-repo inside it, places the input json file inside the clone, renames it to input.json and runs mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="MyMavenProject".
The problem arises when somebody pushes several jsons at once to data-repo. This triggers several parallel pipeline runs and several parallel executions of mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="MyMavenProject". What ends up happening is that the mvn commands appear to get stuck.
When debugging the issue, I tried sending 2 mvn --version commands in parallel instead, and they got "stuck" for 30 secs before printing the output. It seems like sending 2 mvn commands in parallel is causing some interference, but I'm not sure why, since my knowledge of Java and Maven is very limited and Google was of no help.
Has anyone encountered this or has any idea on how to solve this?

Having several mvn running on the same working dir will likely cause problems. Also, it might cause problems if they share the same local repository. My question would be: Why do you do this? Why not build the project once, create a JAR and then use that JAR?

It would be very relevant to see a thread dump showing where it is stuck.

@JFabianMeier The maven runs are executed from different dirs. Each jsonl created its own run dir, with its own clone of the work-repo. Will 2 parallel invocations of the jar be completely independent (I mean, they sort of use the same maven as well, don't they)?

@Alice312 Parallel invocations are independent, unless the code contains problems in this direction, like e.g. using the same file.
